# Using .bat scripts to automate file copying

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I'm working with traces of test executions. There is one file (traces/trace.txt), where the last test's trace is stored and I'd like to write a script to store old versions of this file.

Here's what I've done:

-created a folder for file versions "AllTraces"

I have wrote a script "trace_archive.bat" for copying a file with trace to this folder and concatenating date and time to the name:

```
set source=c:\some_path\traces\trace.txt
set destination=c:\somepath\AllTraces\
xcopy %source% %destination% /y
cd %destination%
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
set datetime=%datetime:~0,8%-%datetime:~8,6%
ren "trace.txt" "trace_%datetime%.txt"
```

So, in this folder I'll have files with a names like this:

- trace_20161117-095910.txt
- trace_20161117-105713.txt
- etc.

-created a folder "LastTrace"

The idea is to store a copy of last version of trace there and compare traces/trace.txt to it. If there's a difference, than we now that new test was executed, so we launch trace_archive.txt to make a copy to AllTraces and replace trace.txt in LastTrace with a current version of traces/trace.txt.
So, I've created a script "TraceTrigger.bat":

```
 set noDiff = "FC: no differences encountered"
 FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`fc /b C:\some_path\AllTraces\LastTrace\trace.txt c:\some_path\traces\trace.txt`) 
 DO (
 SET result=%%F
)
if NOT %noDiff% == %result% (
c:some_path\scripts\trace_archive.bat
del /f c:sope_path\AllTraces\LastTrace\trace.txt
xcopy c:\Users\akomedat\AppData\Local\Temp\.FLT\traces\trace.txt   c:Users\akomedat\AllTraces\LastTrace\
)
```

This script doesn't work as expected. For sure, it doesn't execute the trace_archive.bat and doesn't copy file to AllTraces. Here's the output I'm getting:

```
C:\some_path\scripts>TraceTrigger.bat

C:\some_path\scripts>set noDiff = "FC: no differences encountered"

C:\some_path\scripts>FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN (`fc /b C:\some_path\AllTraces\LastTrace\trace.txt c:\some_path\tra
ces\trace.txt`) DO (SET result=%F )

C:\some_path\scripts>(SET result=Comparing files C:\some_path\ALLTRACE
S\LASTTRACE\trace.txt and C:\some_path\TRACES\TRACE
.TXT )

C:\some_path\scripts>(SET result=FC: C:\some_path\ALLTRACES\LASTTRACE\
trace.txt longer than C:\some_path\TRACE.TXT
 )
C:\some_path\ALLTRACES\LASTTRACE\trace.txt was unexpected at this time.

C:\some_path\scripts>if NOT  == FC: C:\some_path\ALLTRACES\LASTTRACE\t
race.txt longer than C:\some_path\TRACES\TRACE.TXT
(
```

How to fix TraceTrigger.bat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always better to cut-and-paste *actual* code. A manual edit (some_path/so**p**e_path) can set off a wild-goose chase.

At least one problem with your code is in this line:

```
if NOT %noDiff% == %result% (
```

Since `nodiff` and `result` may each contain spaces, you need to `"quote both sides"`, ie

```
if NOT "%noDiff%"=="%result%" (
```

Note that the quoting causes `cmd` to see each quoted string as a single string.

But your code is way too complex.

```
 fc /b C:\some_path\AllTraces\LastTrace\trace.txt c:\some_path\traces\trace.txt >nul
 if errorlevel 1 (
  echo files did not match
  CALL c:some_path\scripts\trace_archive.bat
  del /f c:sope_path\AllTraces\LastTrace\trace.txt
  xcopy c:\Users\akomedat\AppData\Local\Temp\.FLT\traces\trace.txt   c:Users\akomedat\AllTraces\LastTrace\
 ) else (
  echo files matched
 )
```

`fc` sets `errorlevel` to 0 on match, 1 on non-match. You would need to `CALL` the other batch file - if you simply `EXECUTE` that batch, then processing is *transferred* to that batch - it will only return when the other batch finishes if you `CALL` it.